# ThreeJS mesh positioning

Tags: three.js, positioning

I'm discovering the world of Three.js. While creating a datavisualization of the world I need to add data to it. Here is where I'm stuck. 
I created a circle, and added a box to it(height ranging on data). I want to add the box on the edge of the circle, right the center of the box is on the edge. How do I get the innerside of the box to be 'starting point' of positioning? So no parts of the boxes will dissapear inside the circle?

The placement of the box is done in this code:

```
  geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, value);`enter code here`

  testObject = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
  testObject.position = new THREE.Vector3(500, 500, 500);
  var lat = 51.6979;
  var lng = 5.317;
  var phi = (90 - lat) * Math.PI / 180;
  var theta = (180 - lng) * Math.PI / 180;
  testObject.position.x = radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
  testObject.position.y = radius * Math.cos(phi);
  testObject.position.z = radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obxh95v3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I got you right, then after

```
var theta = ...;
```

add

```
radius += value / 2;
```